# generate random numbers in python with quotes

Tags: python, json, list, random

Requirement:
`["123456","578758",......"837872"]` a list of random 6 digit numbers **with quotes**

What I have tried:

```
res = random.sample(range(10000, 999999), 45)
for i in range(5000):  
  print ('{"products":'+'"'+str(res)+'"'+'}')
  print("\n")
```

I am new to python so please do suggest how can I achieve the requirement

I also wish to know how this question is duplicated when I can't find any similarities in other questions on StackOverflow. (The requirement is different it is not about generating random numbers)

Comment: `res = list(map(str, random.sample(range(100000, 999999), 45)))`

Comment: Do you really need double quotes?

Comment: I think you're missing a ```0``` in ```10000```, should be ```100000``` to get 6 digit numbers

Comment: @HughMungus that's fine

Comment: What if I need double quotes instead of single codes, what @Matiiss suggested works with single quotes

Comment: @Sprivro subclass `str` and override `__repr__` method, to do this inline you can use `res = list(map(type("", (str,), {"__repr__": lambda self: f"\"{self}\""}), random.sample(range(100000, 999999), 45)))`, basically in that first comment replace `str` by `type("", (str,), {"__repr__": lambda self: f"\"{self}\""})`, but normally you'd want to use normal `class` syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
[str(x) for x in random.sample(range(10000, 999999), 45)]
```

Comment: Questions as basic as this have usually already been asked and answered on Stack Overflow. Please look for a duplicate and flag/vote to close (if you have that [privilege](/help/privileges)) instead of adding an answer.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Sorry but I couldn't find any questions related to mine so had to create a new one

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues with your syntax.

1. You're taking 45 random samples despite only needing 6
2. You wrote a loop that performs 5000 iterations
3. Your print statement is strange

**Issue 1**

The second argument passed to `random.sample` specifies the number of samples you want. If you truly want 6 random samples the syntax should be: `random.sample(range(10000, 9999999), 6)`

**Issue 2**

When you say `for i in something`, you are instructing your loop to iterate through each item in `something`. In your case it is the numbers 0-4999. This is besides the point because you don't need a loop to accomplish your objective.

**Issue 3**

As stated above, you don't need to use a for loop for this. But if you really wanted to, construct it like this:

```
for i in res: 
    print(str(res))
```

**A better way to do this:**

I'm going to go out on a limb and assume you want these values stored in an array due to your description of your requirement.

If that's the case I recommend using [map](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/).

This would look like:

```
list(map(str, random.sample(range(10000, 9999999), 6)))
```

If you want to print them:

```
print(*list(map(str, random.sample(range(10000, 9999999), 6))), sep='\n')
```

**Outputs**

```
list(map(str, random.sample(range(10000, 9999999), 6)))
OUTPUT>>> ['1696162', '394420', '9290621', '624215', '3367247', '2571869']

print(*list(map(str, random.sample(range(10000, 9999999), 6))), sep='\n')
OUTPUT>>> 
5957168
446219
611119
6518976
4197232
3394411
```

**Notes**

Quotations won't show in the console when you print strings. Don't worry though. Because we mapped the 6 values to strings, the quotes are there for all intents and purposes.

The asterisk that starts off the print statement tells Python to consider all values.

You also don't have to write a second print statement to create a new line after each value. This can be done by passing the `sep` argument to `print` and assigning it the value of `'\n'` like: `print(*something, sep='\n')`. This will print each new value on a new line.

Comment: they didn't specify the number of samples, they also want to print the list, quotations won't show when printing strings, but when you print a list that contains strings, it prints `repr`esentation of those strings which includes quotes, `*` unpacks all values

Comment: @Matiiss, you're right. I glossed over the 6 digit part and thought the OP meant 6 numbers.

Comment: `print(str(...))` is redundant because `print` implicitly converts output to `str`ing